# Simple way of doing this problem?

Tags: matrices

[image: Question]

I know how to do it by elementary row and column operations but I need a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$A=B^{-1}\cdot C^{-1}\implies B\cdot A \cdot C=I $$

Step by step:

$$B\cdot A \cdot C=I \implies A \cdot C= B^{-1}\cdot I=B^{-1} \implies A= B^{-1}\cdot C^{-1}$$

Comment: you mean A = B^-1 dot C ^ -1 ??

Comment: yes of course, it's a product!

Comment: @ gimusi , here this is possible just because B & C are non-singular. If they were singular, then we have to use elementary operations, I think.

Comment: sorry my friend , if I'm bothering you.

Comment: @Abhishek You are welcome, constructive criticism is positive!

Comment: otherwise, your approach is nice..

Comment: @Abhishek I think that if B or C were not singular there would be no way to obtain I on the LHS.

Comment: then we have to use elementary row / column operations to convert B and C into $I $ , on LHS we'll get A .On the other hand identity matrix of RHS will be converted into some another matrix which will be our A, then.